# How to disable a button based on multiple session values

Tags: php

I have php code that will disable a button if a `$_SESSION['username'] !=` a certain value and it works as expected. If anyone logs in other than bobby@gmail.com, the button is disabled.

```
<button type="button" value="<?=$recipient['recipID'];?>" <?php if ($_SESSION['username'] != 'bobby@gmail.com'){ ?> disabled <?php   } ?>class="editrecipientbtn btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</button>
```

I would like the code to work if bobby@gmail.com or mary@gmail.com logs in. I tried the following code:

```
<button type="button" value="<?=$recipient['recipID'];?>" <?php if ($_SESSION['username'] != 'bobby@gmail.com' || 'mary@gmail.com'){ ?> disabled <?php   } ?>class="editrecipientbtn btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</button>
```

However this disables the button for both logins. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your `|| 'mary@gmail.com'` is not being compared to anything. Try `if (!in_array($_SESSION['username'], array('bobby@gmail.com', 'mary@gmail.com')))`

Comment: user3783243..Thank you for helping to display my code properly. I'll get the hang of properly posting questions.

Comment: user3783243...Trying your suggestion the button is disabled for bobby but enabled for mary.

Comment: I found the solution with the help of an answer on SO provided by Andresch Serj, back in 2013. if ($_SESSION['username'] !== 'bobby@gmail.com' && $_SESSION['username'] !== 'mary@gmail.com'). Now if either bobby or mary logs in, the button is enabled, for anyone else it's disabled.